# Spring boot is taking the default value instead of from application-local.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class which takes a value from the config file but it is not working.

```
@Component
public class InputValidator {

    private final Logger log = ESAPI.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${apis.maxNumOfCics : 88}")
    private Integer maxNumOfCics;

// some methods
}
```

I have configured a random default value of 88 which is being used even though I configured it as 20 in application-local.yml. When i don't use a default value:

```
@Value("${apis.maxNumOfCics}")
```

it takes the correct value from application-local.yml, and I set the the active profile to local as well. The spelling is correct and the other config values are coming from the yml file but when I put a default it always takes the default. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you running your application/setting your profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the spaces in the expression. Try removing the spaces in your expression before and after the `:`.

```java
@Value("${apis.maxNumOfCics:88}")
private Integer maxNumOfCics;
```

Try one of the pieces of syntax from [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#:%7E:text=We%20can%20also%20set%20default%20values%20for%20the%20properties%20or%20keys%20that%20might%20not%20exist%3A)

Comment: wow, thanks it worked! shouldve tried this sooner